# How do you distribute your keystore & passwords to the rest of your team?

Tags: android, cordova

So working on pushing our first build of our app to the various app stores.

Apple provides its own set of challenges and irritations.

Google, however, instead of allowing you to somehow authenticate with your google account (which would make sense to me), wants you to create a keystore with a private key & public cert (which it embeds in your apk). Then every update must have that same cert in order to be pushed to Google Play (if I understand the docs correctly).

So the keystore has a password, the private key has a password, and the keystore resides on your filesystem somewhere. This is all well and fine if you're a solo developer, however I am on a development team and any one of us may want to push an update to the app.

How do you deal with distributing the keystore and passwords in a secure way to your team & onboard new teammates when they arrive?

Comment: this question makes no sense or you got no release policy. Why you care new teammates? Do you allow anyone to release updates to your app at will? Then you can have more problems than you expect

Comment: "Google, however, instead of allowing you to somehow authenticate with your google account (which would make sense to me), wants you to create a keystore with a private key & public cert (which it embeds in your apk)" -- you do not have to have a Google account to develop apps for Android. "Then every update must have that same cert in order to be pushed to Google Play (if I understand the docs correctly)" -- yes, substituting "your preferred distribution channels" where you have "Google Play". The Play Store is but one distribution channel.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Android Studio uses a debug keystore for debugging and debug builds that each developer can use for development on their own dev machine. So you only need to use the release keystore for each final release that you submit to Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for those clarifications @CommonsWare

Comment: Right. Of course I read somewhere on SO that having different debug keystores can be its own problem (something about maps api keys & one dev not able to overwrite another dev's build) @DanielNugent

Comment: @steve Yes, for developing Map apps, you would probably want to create a debug API Key and add the SHA1 values for each dev machine that's being used by all of the different developers (or just leave that part blank for the debug API Key so that the SHA1 value is not needed).  That way you could have one debug API Key that all of the developers use.  Of course the SHA1 of the release keystore would need to be used for the API Key that is used for the final signed apk.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, you don't.  There should only be one person that controls the keystore and passwords because that's who controls who submits it to the Play store.  You certainly don't want new onboard teammates just submitting a new apk whenever they feel the need to.

If you're the head of this team, you should be the only one with it and control when new updates are pushed to the Play store.

Comment: Agreed. Or, if you are into build automation, have a build server configured with this information, and control who is eligible to initiate a release build.

Comment: Also, be sure to backup your keystore somewhere safe.  If you lose that file you will be no longer able to push updates...

Comment: This makes sense to some degree, however we have a small team that run on mutual respect & trust. When we hire a new developer we expect them to have a commit and production release on day 1.

Comment: So I like the idea of build automation and backing up the keystore. How do you do this in a way such that you feel confident it won't be compromised? Since anyone who has that keystore & password(s) can release apks as you.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to or have reason to allow multiple team member access to the Keystore.. you can subversion them. In my experience, they don't seem to be tied to a specific computer. So even if you have to replace your computer, you should still be able to use the Keystore.

Actually that is a smart thing to do anyway. We have several Keystores that got corrupted or who only knows what, but they stopped working. Which means whatever is tied to that Keystore is hosed.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider the keystore itself to be "sensitive" information, and therefore not a good thing to check into version control?